# stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString has no return value

Tags: javascript, objective-c

I have this JS code below and I'm trying to get an return value from this. I'm using stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString to the "exit" string. The alert is called, but I don't get any return value.

```
NSString *backString = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"goBack();"];
```

Are there any issues with the JS Code?

```
function goBack() {
        var currentpage = $('.current').attr('id'); 
        var params=window.location.hash;

            if (params != '#home') {
                window.history.go(-1);
            }else{
                alert("exit");
                return "exit";
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that you do not reference your variable `currentpage`.  Is that an issue?

I also received an empty string by calling `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` with a js call that I had not defined yet.

My solution consisted of 2 parts:

1. Make sure your UIWebView is fully loaded through the async callback of `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView`
2. Make sure your javascript function contains no errors.

Hope that helps.